# Inner join query in Sequelize referencing multiple tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

HOW DO I WRITE BELOW QUERY IN SEQUELIZE?

```
select vdc_id,vdc.name as vdc,
districts.name as district,
states.name as state,
countries.name as country
from vdc
INNER JOIN districts on (vdc.district_id=districts.district_id and vdc.name like 'L%')
INNER JOIN states on (districts.state_id=states.state_id) 
INNER JOIN countries on (states.country_id=countries.country_id)
order by district asc;
```

**Associations :**

**vdc table contains fk_district_id**

```
db.vdc.belongsTo(db.districts,{
  foreignKey:"district_id"
})
db.districts.hasMany(db.vdc,{
  foreignKey:"district_id"
})
```

**districts table contains fk_state_id**

```
db.districts.belongsTo(db.states,{
  foreignKey:"state_id"
})
db.states.hasMany(db.districts,{
  foreignKey:"state_id"
})
```

**states table contains fk_country_id**

```
db.states.belongsTo(db.countries,{
  foreignKey:"country_id"
})
db.countries.hasMany(db.states,{
  foreignKey:"country_id"
})
```

THANKS YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you would need something like the code below. You would need to adjust it to work with your models since they were not provided, but this should give you an idea of what is required to get the query you want.

```
vdc.findAll({
    attributes: ['vcd_id', 'name'],
    include: [
        {
            model: 'districts', // Or districts model
            attributes: [['name', 'district']], // name as district
            required: true, // Use inner join instead of left join
            on: { // Join on district id and name like 'L%'
                'district_id': { [Op.eq]: sequelize.col('districts.district_id') },
                'name': { [Op.like]: 'L%' }
            }
        },
        // Custom join shouldn't be necessary for the following due to foreign key config
        {
            model: 'states',
            attributes: [['name', 'state']],
            required: true
        },
        {
            model: 'countries',
            attributes: [['name', 'country']],
            required: true
        }
    ],
    order: [['district', 'ASC']]
});
```